# How to get the correct date in javascript. The new Date() says invalid date

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting a date in milliseconds from a url using axios and then storing it in duration variable.Then when I log that date it works fine but when I log new Date(date) it shows invalid date.

```
const [duration, setDuration] = useState('')
  const [loading, setLoad, unsetLoad] = useLoading(true)

  useEffect(function () {
    setLoad()
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    let config = {
      headers: {
        'auth-token': token,
      },
    }
    Axios.get(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_KALOORY_BACKEND_URL}/quiz/details?batchId=${params.batchId}&quizId=${params.quizId}`,
      config
    )
      .then((res) => {
        unsetLoad()
        setDuration(res.data.scheduledForDate)
        setDetails(res.data)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        unsetLoad()
      })
  }, [])

  console.log(duration)
  console.log(new Date(duration))
```

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the log for when you pass the milliseconds to `new Date()`, or as you looking at it when you pass `''` which is the initial value of `duration` that you are setting on line 1?

Comment: Please provide the value you are using to create Date
you will not receive duration like this cos you have async call in between your two statements and this way you will not get the value from the axios request

Comment: Yes, this is my log. 1598583990000   Invalid Date...

Comment: Then whats the method to pass the date in the new Date().

Answer (score 0):

You are just facing the async behavior most of the developers face this in the initial stages of development to understand the async behavior and how the callback mechanism works and how the javascript works with async events, timer events and other events which works outside the normal synchronous flow.

```
 Axios.get(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_KALOORY_BACKEND_URL}/quiz/details?batchId=${params.batchId}&quizId=${params.quizId}`,
      config
    )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(duration)
        console.log(new Date(res.data.scheduledForDate))
        unsetLoad()
        setDuration(res.data.scheduledForDate)
        setDetails(res.data)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        unsetLoad()
      })
  }, [])
```

This is the way you should console.log the Date as the async call will not provide you the latest value on duration and

i think if you need the Date object why don't you just set Date before setting the duration.

```
 setDuration(new Date(res.data.scheduledForDate))
```

Comment: This didn't work either. This is the error => "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Invalid Date). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: This is the res.data {
    "quizId": "5f48d62e24c97023588c5f2d",
    "quizName": "another",
    "quizDuration": 20,
    "quizInstructions": "These are the instructions",
    "quizMaxMarks": 10,
    "scheduledForDate": "1598583990000",
    "scheduledEndDate": "1599413400000",
    "course": {
        "_id": "5f47efdd3ed77442f41e3d11",
        "courseTitle": "2"
    },
    "createdBy": {
        "_id": "5f3e920239d48a53f017223c",
        "name": "Rajat"
    },
    "batch": {
        "_id": "5f47efe53ed77442f41e3d15",
        "batchName": "Naya batch2222"
    }
}

Comment: As per the error its not allowing you to pass Object. Try doing 
 setDuration([new Date(res.data.scheduledForDate)])